# Java Regular Expressions For Capital Letters

Tags: java, regex

I am beginning to get familiar with Java, however I still find regular expressions pretty confusing. I need to check if an element has either two capital letters in a row, three capital letters in a row, four capital letters in a row, or one capital letter, a space, and then another capital letter. This is the code I have so far, but I feel like there is a much better (and way more efficient) way to do this.

```
 public class First {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String one = "A scenario - CAPI 200 - 001";
        String two = "A scenario - C T 200 - 001";
        String three = "A scenaRio - CT 200 - 001";
        String four = "A sCenario - CAP 200 - 001";


        Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[A-Z][A-Z][A-Z][A-Z]");
        Pattern q = Pattern.compile("[A-Z] [A-Z]");
        Pattern r = Pattern.compile("[A-Z][A-Z]");
        Pattern s = Pattern.compile("[A-Z][A-Z][A-Z]");

        Matcher m =p.matcher(one);
        if (m.find()){
            System.out.println(m.group());
        }
        Matcher d =q.matcher(two);
        if (d.find()){
            System.out.println(d.group());
        }
        Matcher e =r.matcher(three);
        if (e.find()){
            System.out.println(e.group());
        }
        Matcher a =s.matcher(four);
        if (a.find()){
            System.out.println(a.group());
        }
    }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You can use `{fewest_repetitions<,optional_most_repetitions>}` to denote a part that repeats -- replace `fewest_repetitions` with the lower bound and if you need an upper bound replace `<optional_most_repetitions>`

Comment: Note: Your code only shows two matches because `two` should go with `s`, and `four` should go with `q` (you have the reverse)

Comment: Wow, thanks for all the help. Specifically it needs to check if items in an array list meet these scenarios (they all do) and then print just the capital letters that match the scenario. Is that more clear or confusing?

Comment: @Michelle, nice catch. I just edited my question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use this to match 2-4 Capital letters, or capital, space, capital

```
([A-Z]{2,4})|([A-Z] [A-Z])
```

EDIT:
Just realized you may need to differentiate which group is matching.

In that case, what you are doing isn't wrong, but can be optimized with that `[A-Z]{2}` method to shorten the regex. If you tell us what the code needs to do, we can better come up with solutions to fit your need.

Comment: It would probably be better to combine at least the options without spaces as `[A-Z]{2,4}` and check the length of the match to determine which type it is, rather than using 3 separate regexes.

Comment: the method for which can hopefully be easily deduced from my answer. I will try to update once I know what exactly the goal is here.

Comment: Adam, I can't appreciate your answer enough. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

`{n}` means n times with regular expressions.  You really should use this approach.  So in your case, use

```
[A-Z]{4}
```

to mean 4 times in a row for instance.

Comment: Yea that would make things cleaner. Thanks for the information.

Answer (score 1):

You can probably merge all in a single `Pattern`.

For instance:

```
String[] inputs = {
            // two capital letters in a row
            "AA",
            // three capital letters in a row
            "BBB",
            // four capital letters in a row
            "CCCC",
            // one capital letter, a space, and then another capital letter.
            "D D" };
String pattern = "[A-Z]{2,4}|[A-Z] [A-Z]";
for (String input: inputs) {
    System.out.println(Pattern.matches(pattern, input));
}
```

**Output**

```
true
true
true
true
```

Comment: \s will match any whitespace, including new lines. Just use a literal space.

Comment: @AdamYost true, I thought this was a little underspecified though (OP says "a space")

Comment: @Mena, sorry it was underspecified. I didn't mean whitespace, just a literal space between the characters. Thanks for looking into it.

Comment: Thanks for the response Mena! Your answer is very appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

first , Welcome to the Regex world . Regular expression are used to summarize a set of String pattern into one expression. if for example we would refer to any string that start with a capital letter and contain just alphabetical character and has a length less then 15 then the regex would be : `[A-Z][a-z]{,15}` .

In the example that you put in your question  ,it doesn't use regex as they should be used, you can summarize all cases you want to match in one regular expression , this expression could have an OR operator that will group of regular expression like this :

```
([A-Z]{2})|([A-Z]{3})|([A-Z]{4})|([A-Z] [A-Z])
```

but when the fisrt tree part could be grouped in just one expression using the repitition operator `{[minLenght],[Maxlength]}` , then the expression become :

```
([A-Z]{2,4})|([A-Z] [A-Z])
```

the parentheses order refer to the group order .

Comment: Thank you for the information. I learned more from posting this question than the multiple tutorials I read. Can't appreciate it enough. I wish my reputation was higher so I could up vote your answer.